# Spring cloud stream kafka. Want to send Message<Object> but Spring send Message<Byte[]>. The payload is Byte[] not GenericMessage in JSON format

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I use Spring cloud Stream with kafka, avro, schema registry. I work on reactive programmaing in Functionnal style. I want to produce a message like this.
`GenericMessage [payload={"id": "efb90cd6-e022-4d82-9898-6b78114cfb01", "type": "FirstRankPaymentAgreed",...},  headers={deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=cucumber-test1, contentType=application/json...}]`

But it's produce message like this.
`GenericMessage [payload=byte[2151],  headers={deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=cucumber-test1, contentType=application/json...}]`

```
spring-cloud-stream-schema 2.2.1.RELEASE
spring-cloud-stream 3.2.2
spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka 3.2.5
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams 3.2.5
spring-cloud-function-context 3.2.1
kafka-avro-serializer 5.3.0
spring-kafka 2.9.0
org.apache.avro.avro 1.11.1
```

I am using Reactive Functional Style.

```
Function<Flux<Message<Object>>, Flux<Message>> handler()

return Mono.just(Message<FirstRankPaymentAgreed> messageMessageBuilder = MessageBuilder.withPayload((FirstRankPaymentAgreed) message.getPayload()).build());
```

The result of this producer is received message: `GenericMessage [payload=byte[1056], headers={contentType=application/json, id=7d3b65c1-11d8-0fb2-a277-0603f58fd516, timestamp=1672174971194}]`

In payload we have Byte array not JSON.

i want something like this `GenericMessage [payload={"id": "254335d0-b631-454e-98de-d2d5129af4c0", "type": "ObjectClass", "delta"...`

```
cloud:
  stream:
    function:
      definition: dispatchConsumerFromTempoComposerEvent
    bindings:
      dispatchConsumerFromTempoComposerEvent-in-0:
        destination: tempo-composer-event
      dispatchConsumerFromTempoComposerEvent-out-0:
        destination: tempo-composer-event
        contentType: application/json  --> i try to add this 
    kafka:
      binder:
        auto-create-topics: false
        consumer-properties:
          value:
            subject:
              name:
                strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
          key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
          value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
          schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
          specific.avro.reader: true
        producer-properties:
          value:
            subject:
              name:
                strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy --> i try to add this
          key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
          value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
          schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
```

I Want to migrate project to spring cloud stream. "Legacy" code :

```
private static final JsonGenericRecordReader recordReader = new JsonGenericRecordReader(new CompositeJsonToAvroReader(List.of(), IGNORE_UNKNOWN_FIELD));
```

```
private static KafkaProducer<String, Object> buildProducer() {
        final var config = new Properties();
        config.put("bootstrap.servers", KafkaConfiguration.kafkaHost());
        config.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        config.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
        config.put("schema.registry.url", "http://" + KafkaConfiguration.schemaRegistryHost());
        config.put("value.subject.name.strategy", TopicRecordNameStrategy.class.getName());
        return new KafkaProducer<>(config);
    }
```

```
final var getClassSchema = avroClass.getMethod("getClassSchema");
            final var specificRecord = recordReader.read(record.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), (Schema) getClassSchema.invoke(null));
            final var producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, Object>(topic, key, specificRecord);
            if (TestContext.traceId() != null) {
                producerRecord.headers().add("b3", (TestContext.traceId() + "-" + TestContext.traceId() + "-1").getBytes());
            }
            headers.forEach((name, value) -> producerRecord.headers().add(name, value.getBytes()));
            TestContext.additionalKafkaHeaders().forEach((name, value) -> producerRecord.headers().add(name, value.getBytes()));

            RecordMetadata recordMetadata = getProducer().send(producerRecord).get();
            return recordMetadata;
```

this legacy code produce

```
GenericMessage [payload={"id": "efb90cd6-e022-4d82-9898-6b78114cfb01", "type": "FirstRankPaymentAgreed",...},  headers={deliveryAttempt=1, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedMessageKey=cucumber-test1, contentType=application/json...}]
```

Payload is in JSON format. And after my migration spring cloud stream I have [payload=byte[2151]...

Comment: You want to send Avro? Then why do you have `contentType=application/json`? If you want Avro, then byte array is what you need

Comment: My consumer got Message with Payload in JSON. I want to use DLQ if necessary. For now i just send Message in the same topic for testing. And my consumer got Message with Payload in Byte[] not JSON.

Comment: When first message come o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'dispatchConsumerFromTempoComposerEvent-in-0'', message: GenericMessage [payload={"id": "19921c9c-eb51-491f-9b91-6e0491ecedd9", "type": "FirstRankPaymentAgreed",..... and when my message produce by my producer come  o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'dispatchConsumerFromTempoComposerEvent-out-0'', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[2151], headers={contentType=application/json ...

Comment: As I said, Avro is `byte[]`. Your value serializer isn't using JSON for any of the binder properties, so I don't understand what you're looking for

Comment: i added some informations to explain what i want et my probleme. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i used this signature Function<Flux<Message<FirstRankPaymentAgreed>>, Flux<Message<FirstRankPaymentAgreed>>> it's work fine. But With this Function<Flux<Message<Object>>, Flux<Message>> Consumer can't convert Avro Byte to the right object. So I can't make specific class object because we consume différent Type in one topic.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use Object because of type erasure. Use SpecificRecord or GenericRecord instead

Comment: I have already tested both. I even tested "?" lol and even  Message without the diamonds. org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a Specific class: interface org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord
Not working. I am determined and desperate at the same time

Comment: I have one topic with multiple event Type. How i can use Function<Flux<Message>, Flux<Message>> ? With juste one event type it's work fine when i use Function<Flux<Message<Person>>, Message<Personn>>>

Comment: IDK why you get "Not a Specific class" error. But the only want to support multiple Avro types via generics is to use `<GenericRecord>`. A raw `Message` (without diamond) probably would work as well, but then you still need to cast each value manually, and handle ClassCastException

Comment: Using GenericRecord application/json (application.yml) ( i have reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Comment: Using GenericRecord application/avro (application.yml) org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No schema can be inferred from type org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord and no schema has been explicitly configured.

Comment: Using Message application/json org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.messaging.Message` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Comment: Using Message application/avro Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.messaging.Message.<init>()

Comment: those error appear when my produce produce this message  o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : postSend (sent=true) on channel 'bean 'dispatchConsumerFromTempoComposerEvent-out-0'', message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[1056], headers={contentType=application/avro, id=7d4a3a50-0b37-bcbd-8580-0721cb3ae2ef, timestamp=1672827013200}]
and my consumer try to read it.

Comment: When my conssumer read this message o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'dispatchConsumerFromTempoComposerEvent-in-0'', message: GenericMessage [payload={"id": "dd2b9f25-1c52-4944-80ca-c2e552ec0994", "type": "FirstRankPaymentAgreed", "delta": {..Continuation JSON...}, headers={...}]
all works fine.

Comment: Avro is Byte ok. If my producer produce payload on json format it's solved my pb. How i can do it and using avro schema to secure data. Serialize object to json using avro schema to secure data ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include changes you've tried and formatted logs/errors, not use several comments... I don't have Spring Cloud Stream experience, so I cannot really help much. Avro does not "secure" anything. You use TLS with Kafka to secure **the topic**.

Answer (score 0):

I simply using schema registry. Instead use message payload to retrive class and get schema to convert byte array to final avro schema. I use schema registry and id. Ignored thirst byte and get id of schema to find right schema. You can juste annotate you application.class and add @EnableSchemaRegistry. Your signature Function it's look like this.

```
@Bean
public Function<Flux<Message<Object>>, Flux<Message<Object>>>
```

Spring cloud stream read byte array get id of schema. Find right schema on schema registry and convert byte array into right class.